# Sum of an Array in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, sum

In google Apps script i am pulling rows of numbers into an array

I need to find the sum of every element in that array

This code works fine: (This is pulling the values into the array)

```
   var test = [];
   test = sheet.getRange(13, 6, 4, 24).getValues();
```

I've tried a couple different formulas i've found and haven't been able to get it to work right:

```
 function testSum (test) {
 let total = 0;
 for (const i of test) {
 total += i;
 }
 return total;
 }


 var test1 = test.flat();

 var test1 = test.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Tried everything i could find and nothing would work

Comment: What is the test input giving value ? can you show me an example ?

Comment: When i log test.typeOf it returns undefined

When i console log test i get

[ [ 583.95,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    225,
    '',
    11,
    '',
    20,
    '',
    21.95,
    '',
    279,
    '',
    19,
    '',
    8,
    '',
    690,
    '',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ 145,
    '',
    80,
    '',
    10,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    55,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    110,
    '',
    '',
    '' ],
  [ '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',]...

Comment: the elements shown in the array are columns and every column shows the rows ? that what I get

Comment: I thought that if `test` of `var test1 = test.flat();` is `test` of `test = sheet.getRange(13, 6, 4, 24).getValues();`, how about modifying `var test1 = test.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);` to `var test1 = test.flat().reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b), 0);`? By this, `test1` might be your expected result. Because, in your current script, `test` is a 2-dimensional array. If I misunderstood your actual script, I apologize.

Comment: Getting a ".reduce is not a function" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const test = [
      [
        583.95,
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        225,
        '',
        11,
        '',
        20,
        '',
        21.95,
        '',
        279,
        '',
        19,
        '',
        8,
        '',
        690,
        '',
        '',
        '',
      ],
      [
        145,
        '',
        80,
        '',
        10,
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        55,
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        110,
        '',
        '',
        '',
      ],
      ['', '', '', '', ''],
    ];
    
    const columnWiseSums = [];
    
    for (const ele  of test) {
        let sum = 0;
        columnWiseSums.push(ele.reduce((prev, curr) =>  typeof curr === 'number' ? prev + curr : prev, 0));
    }
console.log(columnWiseSums);
```

There are other ways to find sum as well, but I used  `array.reduce` one

Comment: This worked, Thank you !

Comment: @DavidAbbott Welcome, Don't forget to upvote/mark as answer as I can't ask questions in case chatgpt is unable to help as well.

Comment: I need the sums of each element to stay in their own element so i can push that sum back into sheets.  When i go to push it back now it just assigns test[0] value to every cell

Comment: @DavidAbbott you can take separate array for sums

Answer (score 0):

1. For `1D` array

```js
     const sumOfArrayElement = (input) => {
             return input.reduce((total, item)=>total+item)
     }
     console.log(sumOfArrayElement([3,2,4]));
```

2. For `2D` Array

```
     const sum = [];
     const test = [ 
                    [1,2,3], 
                    [ 3,4,5]
                  ];
     test.forEach(item => {
         sum.push(item.reduce((total,num)=> {
             return num!= ''?total +parseFloat(num):total;
         }));
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will be make the mistake solucion.

```js
function testSum(test) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < test[i].length; j++) {
    
      if (typeof test[i][j] == "number") {
        sum += test[i][j]
      }
    }
  }
  return sum
}
```